# How to show firstname of the user in grails with shiro

Tags: grails, shiro, principal

i am new to grails and trying to show the firstname  of the user with: "shiro:principal property="firstName"

but it gives me the following error:

```
Error executing tag 'shiro:principal': No such property: firstName for class: java.lang.String
```

If i just to use "shiro:principal" it does print the username, but i need first name.

the domain class looks like this:

```
class ShiroUser {

    String firstName
    String lastName
    String username
```

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can see the code here: https://github.com/pledbrook/grails-shiro/blob/master/grails-app/taglib/org/apache/shiro/grails/ShiroTagLib.groovy#L119

It looks to me that you might have to include `type="ShiroUser"` so that it gets a principal with the correct class.

So your GSP tag would be `<shiro:principal type="ShiroUser" property="firstName" />`

**Update:**

I've had a look at our code and it turns out we don't use this feature (I thought we did). We actually wrote our own tag library to achieve what you are asking about. So maybe this was a problem for us too?

So this is a tag library which we created:
UserTagLib.groovy

```
def loggedInUser = { attrs, body ->
    def user = _currentUser()

    if (!user) return

    def prop = user[attrs.property]

    if (prop) out << prop.encodeAsHTML()
}

def _currentUser() {
    def principal = SecurityUtils.subject?.principal

    if (!principal) return // No-one logged-in

    return User.get(principal)
}
```

An example usage:
`<user:loggedInUser property="fullName"/>`

Comment: i tried this but this does not return anything just a blank. do you know any other way i can pass those entity value from domain via controller to gsp?

Comment: Your solution worked for me, @David. Thanks. But it needed a bit of tweaking in `_currentUser() {}`. I'll post it in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what @David posted I was able to make it work for me. This is what I did:

```
package myproject

import com.somepackage.ShiroUser
import org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils

class UserTagLib {
static defaultEncodeAs = [taglib:'html']
//static encodeAsForTags = [tagName: [taglib:'html'], otherTagName: [taglib:'none']]
static namespace = "user"

def loggedInUser = { attrs, body ->
    def user = _currentUser()

    if (!user) return

    def prop = user[attrs.property]

    if (prop) out << prop.encodeAsHTML()
}

    def _currentUser() {

        def subject = SecurityUtils.subject

        if (!subject.getPrincipal()) return // No-one logged-in

        return User.findByUsername(subject.getPrincipal().toString())
    }

}
```

(modified part is in `_currentUser()`)

And then in the view:

```
...

<div class="someClass">
   <shiro:isLoggedIn>Hello, <user:loggedInUser property="fullName"/> </shiro:isLoggedIn>
</div>

...
```

Comment: Thanks, just want to mention this tag lib works only if domain authentication called `User`, so we must to change user domain name accordinally.